# How to change code in current build in iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I currently have a build in iTunes connect that i'm using for Test Flight's internal testing. I changed the code in the Xcode project to improve it. I thought I have to go to Xcode project and submit the project with the altered code however, iTunes Connect doesn't let me upload another build because it says 1 already exists. So how do I change the code on the build that exists in iTunes connect?

Can I just delete the current build in iTunes connect so I can re-submit my Xcode project? If so, how do I delete it?

Answer (score 2):

You probably just need to change the build number.

You are not allowed to have more than one app with the same build number.

Go to the project target, select General, under Identity change the Build field.